# How to skip waiting service worker in Vue PWA

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, skip

I use the VUE PWA service worker plugin for my pwa.

I wanna run the new service worker if any new exisits, but don't know how to include it in my code.
At the moment the current service worker not even updates after 24h. Only if the user closes the browser and clearing the cache. But that's not what I want of course.

So, how can I implement the skipWaiting() ?

Here's my registerServiceWorker.js

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
     register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
          ready() {
               console.log(
                    'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n' +
                         'For more details, visit '
               )
          },
          registered() {
               console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
          },
          cached() {
               console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
          },
          updatefound() {
               console.log('New content is downloading.')
          },
          updated(registration) {
               console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
               document.dispatchEvent(
                    new CustomEvent('swUpdated', { detail: registration })
               )
          },
          offline() {
               console.log(
                    'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
               )
          },
          error(error) {
               console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
          },
     })
}
```

The code in the updated part generates this waiting to activate at least.

[image: Screenshot Console]

Comment: the service worker only updates after you change atleast 1 byte in your service worker (for exmple renaming your service worker cache). and he only updates if you close every session you have in your browser

Comment: by "session", @lfaruki means all tabs and windows that have the site open

Answer (score 0):

**Solution without modification to the `service-worker.js` file**

In your `registerServiceWorker.js` file modify the `updated` function to send a message to the default service worker with the code

```js
updated (registration) {
  registration.waiting.postMessage({ type: 'SKIP_WAITING' })
}
```

---

**Solution with modification to the `service-worker.js` file**

In your custom `service-worker.js` file add a listener with the code

```js
self.addEventListener('install', () => self.skipWaiting())
```